# Render polygons in order north to south down in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rendering, draw-order

In QGIS I have a set of polygons that I want to render in the order north to south:

[image]

I understand that `Control feature rendering order` in the Symbology dialog is the option I need.
I came up with the expression `y_min($geometry)`, but that does not change anything.

Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `y_max`, `x_min`, `x_max`?

Comment: Yes, no effect…